# Why is there an additional translation matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrices

A square object is defined by points $(2,2)$, $(2,4)$, and $(4,2)$. The square is scaled up by factor $3$, and rotated clockwise $45$ degrees about its centre. Demonstrate the composite matrix of the operations with detailed calculations.

[image: Answer Provided]

In the answer, there is an additional translation matrix provided and I am unsure where it was derived from.

I assume it would be to centre the object? Any confirmation or valid reason is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using $3\times3$ matrices instead of $2\times 2$ matrices. Moreover, the translation matrix $T$ is not invertible since the last row is $(0,0,0)$. I guess the last entry should be $1$.

Comment: My lecturer provided the answer, I have been trying to understand it, but i don't seem to get his working at all.

Comment: It's a pretty standard trick to use $ 3 \times 3$ matrices for affine transformations (that is, transformations of the form $x \rightarrow Ax + b$ for some matrix $A$).  The reason is that translations $x \rightarrow x + b$ are not linear (since $0$ doesn't map to $0$) and so can't be represented by a $2 \times 2$ matrix.  So instead, you pad each vector with an extra $1$ at the end and represent translations using $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: You need the translation here because the rotation is about the center of the square, not about the origin, and the rotation matrix rotates about the origin.  So you translate to the origin, rotate, and translate back.

Comment: This translation matrix doesn't look right, though.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)#Matrix_representation

Comment: @JairTaylor, I never used that approach. Thank for your explanation :)

Comment: I am worried by the translation used. When we stretch the centre of the new square is at $(9,9)$ and we ought to rotate about that point.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, the lower-right element of the translation matrix $T$ should be $1$, not $0$. That aside, the rotation matrix $R$ rotates about the origin. In order to perform the same rotation about an arbitrary center, you need to translate the origin to that point, apply $R$, then translate back.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, you might work with $2\times 2$ matrices with a different approach. Since the center of the square in $(3,3)$, you may change the coordinate so that the square has the center at $(0,0)$.

Define $T
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
x-3\\
y-3
\end{pmatrix}$

and $S
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
3x\\
3x
\end{pmatrix}$

Finally the rotation matrix:

$R
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
x\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-y\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\\
x\sin\frac{\pi}{4}+y\cos\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{pmatrix}$

The transformation $M$ you are looking for is $$M=T^{-1}RST.$$

More precisely

$$M
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=T^{-1}RS
\begin{pmatrix}
x-3\\
y-3
\end{pmatrix}=
\cdots=T^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
(3x-9)\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-(3y-9)\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\\
(3x-9)\sin\frac{\pi}{4}+(3y-9)\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
(3x-9)\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-(3y-9)\sin\frac{\pi}{4}+3\\
(3x-9)\sin\frac{\pi}{4}+(3y-9)\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I never used the method described by @Jair Taylor. However, since he is working on a plane a different approach with $2\times 2$ matrices is possible. In my answer I use it.

Comment: I've deleted my comment since the edit.

Comment: I do not believe that the translation $T$ commutes with the stretch $S$. Look at the image of $(0,0)$ under $ST$ and $TS$.  After all, in your 2-d version, $S$ does not have a matrix, does it?

Comment: Yes you right, they do not commute, but $S$ is described as the diagonal matrix with the length of stretching in the diagonal.

Comment: But look at the origin: you say it goes to $(3,3-9\sqrt{2})$. But the question says (i) scale by $3$ - this fixes the origin and sends the centre of the square to $(9,9)$ (ii) rotate by $\pi/4$ about centre of square, and this will send the origin to a point vertically below the centre of the square, that is to $(9,9-9\sqrt{2})$. I suggest that you are wrong to translate before scaling,hence  my remark on non-commutativity.

Comment: to reply to your previous comment, I apologise, it is $T$ which is not given by a $2\times 2$ matrix, so the fact $S$ is scalar does not help.